# How to use IO multiplexing technology to improve server concurrency performance?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I want to make a server software similar to Apache on windows platforms.
. The client sends data to the specified server port and the server responds accordingly. In order to improve the client access speed, I want to use "select" to improve the performance of the server, but there are many problems in the use process.
Here is my code;

### Function "create_server"

This function is used to create the server Socket and set it to non-blocking.

```
int create_server(char*ip_address,int port) {
WORD sockVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
WSADATA wsaData;
if(WSAStartup(sockVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
{
    return 0;
}
int server_socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
int ret = -1;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
if (server_socket == -1) {
    return -1;
}
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr= INADDR_ANY;
ret = bind(server_socket,(LPSOCKADDR)&addr,sizeof(addr));
if (ret == -1) {
    perror("bind error！");
    return -2;
}
listen(server_socket,5);
SetBlock(server_socket, 0);
return server_socket;}
```

### Function "SetBlock"

This function is used to change the socket blocking mode.

```
int SetBlock(int sock, int isblock){
  int re = 0;
  unsigned long ul = 0;
  if (!isblock) ul = 1;
  re = ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, (unsigned long*)& ul);
  if (re != 0) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

### Function "main"

```
int main() {
int s = create_server("127.0.0.1",6666);
int client_socket = -1;
struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
int addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
char buf[1025];
int buffersize=1,result=0;
int isread = 0;
fd_set server;
struct timeval timeout;
int fd = 0;
timeout.tv_sec = 3;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
FD_ZERO(&server);
FD_SET(s, &server);

while (1) {
    result = select(FD_SETSIZE, &server, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (result < 1) {
        perror("error！");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (FD_ISSET(s, &server)) {
        //if server can be readable and written do this
            client_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*) & clientaddr, &addrlen);
            while (buffersize > 0) {
                    buffersize = recv(client_socket, buf, 1024, 0);
                    buf[buffersize] = '\0';
                    printf("%s", buf);
                    if (buffersize < 1024) {
                        break;
                    }
            }
            buffersize = 1;
    }

}


return 0;}
```

As you know, TCP takes some time to establish a connection. I want to use the "select" function to reduce the setup time of multi-client connections. I think the function "accept" is the process of establishing connection between client and server, but how to use IO multiplexing in this process, please help me.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I know this is not what you asked, but do you really have to use the Win32 API directly? In my experience its very hard to use without any benefit. I recommend to use a portable library like boost asio. Still good luck.

Comment: If you're on Windows, read up on I/O Completion Ports instead of using `select()` for best performance.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.Your comments have taught me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the use of `select()` will delay all client connections to the server.

suggest a sequence similar to:

```
create a thread pool
create a sockaddr_in
sock_t serverSock = socket()
bind()
listen()
while( 1 )
{
    sock_t clientSock = accept( serverSock, ... )
    pass clientSock to available thread and mark thread as 'busy'
}
```

That way, the communication with a client does not 'hang' on a `select()`, nor a `accept()`

in each thread:

```
while(1)
{
    wait until thread marked as 'busy'
    sock_t mySocket = passedSocket
    perform all communication with the specific client
    close( mySocket );
    mark thread as 'idle'
}
```

Comment: You have paid a lot for my question, so I really appreciate your answer!.Your answer have taught me a lot!